# pandas reset_index generate name for size column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So i'm trying to change the series generated from groupby function to dataframe by doing reset_index

```
casts = pd.read_csv('cast.csv', index_col=None)
c_decade = casts.groupby(['type',casts['year']//10*10]).size()
df = c_decade.reset_index()
print(df)
```

This is the result

```
       type  year      0
0     actor  1910    384
1     actor  1920    710
2     actor  1930   2628
3     actor  1940   3014
4     actor  1950   2877
5     actor  1960   2775
6     actor  1970   3044
7     actor  1980   3565
8     actor  1990   5108
9     actor  2000  10368
10    actor  2010  15523
11    actor  2020      4
12  actress  1910    285
13  actress  1920    411
14  actress  1930    820
15  actress  1940    983
16  actress  1950   1015
17  actress  1960    968
18  actress  1970   1299
19  actress  1980   1989
```

My question is how to remove the 0 beside the year column? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming the series generated by the groupby:

```
c_decade = casts.groupby(['type',casts['year']//10*10]).size().rename('sizes')
```

The reset_index and print.

Comment: I don't really want to change the column's name to sizes but i got the idea. thank you!